# MySQL connection via SSH tunnel on MacOS doesn't work

Tags: mysql, ssh, vpn, mac-osx, terminal

I've been trying to set up a SSH tunnel with VPN on my macbook with Big Sur 11.2, but it doesn't seem to work.

On my linux machine, I can simply turn on the VPN and make a SSH-tunnel. Then I can just connect to the MySQL server via port `3307`. If I do the same on my macbook, the SSH tunnel does connect, but I can't connect to the MySQL server on the given port.

My exact steps are:

1. Turn on VPN so I can access the server via SSH.
2. Run `ssh -g -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 user@ip_address` in the terminal.
3. Run `mysql -u user -p -h [IP] -P 3307` to connect to the MySQL SSH tunnel.
4. Error: `Can't connect to MySQL server on '[IP]'`.

Above works fine on my linux system, but not on my mac. I am able to SSH to the server with the command, but the tunnel itself is not working.

Is there some reason this is happening, and how should I proceed?

Comment: What are the exact steps you take when trying to connect, and what is the error message?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL connection command tries to connect to the IP of the MySQL server, but that isn't available via the internet.

You need to use `mysql -u user -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307` command on the Macbook to connect via the tunnel.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't not test it out.. I simply thought because it was VPN connected, I had to use that IP. Thanks!